# Read unknown file names from directory

Tags: java, file, directory

I would like to read a file from a directory. In this directory there are eight additional files with the same extension (.csv). Likewise, the file name is not directly known.
The name of the file looks like this:

test_file_1_2017_06_24.csv

It can change however, if I call the directory the next day . Then the file name is:

test_file_2_2017_06_25.csv or test_file_1_2017_06_25.

The name of the file and the date change.
Is there a way to read the file "variable" in Java or to read the file but don´t know the exactly name? The directory is always the same ("H:/) (After the file read, then the file respectively the resulting string is furtherprocessed with split() ).
Thanks for helpfull answers!

Edit: Read the directory and shows only csv-Files

```
File dir = new File("H:/");

    File[] fileArray = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {  

        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".csv");
        }
    });
    for(File f: fileArray){
        System.out.println(f.getName());
    }
```

Comment: You can read the names of all the files in a directory (see `File::listFiles`) but how will you know which is the right one? Are the additional files named completely differently, or can they be confused with the one you want?

Comment: The files are very similar to the content & can be distinguished only by the filename. Temperature values ​​are stored in the CSV files. These are to be analyzed from a total of 8 groups, and each group will of course analyze their own values. In your opinion, is there any way to always read out exactly one file without knowing the exact name?

Comment: I still don't understand if it is possible to determine which file you want. Of course it is possible to read exactly one file, but if the files are named test_file_1_2017_06_25.csv and test_file_2_2017_06_25.csv, how will you decide which one to use? If there is some way *you* would know which one is right, then of course you can program the computer to pick based on the same criteria.

Comment: How can I "filter" the files? I mean, how can I work with exactly the file that ends with "1", for example? For example, all files I need ending with test_file_1?
On another machine I can then make the same with the "2", so all files, which are called test_file_2. I am sorry if I have expressed myself incomprehensibly

Comment: Once you have the filename in a string, you can do anything you would normally do with strings such as startsWith, endsWith, charAt, substring, split, use regular expressions, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File directory = new File("H:/");

File[] allFilesInDir = directory.listFiles();
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles().

You can also provide a [`FilenameFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) to get only .csv files:

```
File[] allCsvFiles = directory.listFiles( new FilenameFilter() {
  public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    if ( name.toUpperCase().endsWith(".CSV") ) {
      return new File(dir,name).isFile(); // Make sure we don't accept sub-directories ending in .csv
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It's `toUpperCase()`. Also, `FilenameFilter` is a functional interface, so you don't need an anonymous inner class. You can just write `directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.toUpperCase().endsWith("CSV") && new File(dir, name).isFile())`

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to call a specific CSV file from the directory without knowing the exact name of the CSV-file?

Comment: Once you have the list of all .csv files you can do whatever you want with it. For example iterate over all of them and check on each one if it is currently of interest to you, then process it.

Comment: Many Thanks! The files are very similar to the content & can be distinguished only by the filename. Temperature values ​​are stored in the CSV files. These are to be analyzed from a total of 8 groups, and each group will of course analyze their own values. In your opinion, is there any way to always read out exactly one file without knowing the exact name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to go through a folder, check for csv files and work with it. Hope it helps.

```
File folder = new File("H:/"); /*path to your folder*/
    String[] filesPresent = folder.list();
    if(filesPresent.length==0){
        System.out.println("Nothing to delete");
    }else{
        for(String fileName : filesPresent){  // looping through files in the directory
            if(fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv") && (new File(fileName).isFile())){
                //this is a csv file.
                //you can do your operations here
                File file = new File(fileName);
                //now you can do any file operations required with the file object
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I view the CSV files from the directory on the console?
System.out.println (file.getName) does not work. 
Is it possible to call a specific CSV file from the directory without knowing the exact name of the CSV-file?

Comment: you want to see filenames from the directory or content of csv files from the directory?

Comment: Both. First, all csv files in the directory should be displayed  on the console. (System.out.println (file.getName) does not work.) Afterwards, the contents of a certain CSV file are to be split & displayed as graphs.

Comment: It is `System.out.println(file.getName())` and it certainly will work.

Comment: It doesn´t work anymore. So I edit my question with code that works